# save and show scraping image with nokogiri rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, screen-scraping, nokogiri

**UPDATE 2**

i use nokogiri to download content and images to a rails app. For this, i write the  script/scraping.rb file:

```
require 'open-uri'

page_url = "<site_url>"

url = "<page_of_site_url>"
b = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

b.css(".col").each do |item|
    img_url = item.at(".field-content a img")['src'].split('?')[0]
    root_img_url = URI.join(page_url,img_url).to_s
    file = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'assets', 'images', File.basename(root_img_url)), 'wb') do |f|
        f.write(open(root_img_url).read)
    end
    Book.create(
        :cover => File.basename(root_img_url),
        :title => item.at_css(".views-field-title a").text,
        :onsaledate => item.at_css(".date-display-single")['content'])
    end
end
```

then i run the script in the terminal:

```
rails runner script/scraping.rb
```

Seconds later, i have my database with the content info, and the images in the folder assets/images.

Thanks to @JoshLewis for his interest and special thanks to @mario_chavez for his help.

Comment: In most databases, you can't store a 'file' in a column. It is a common approach to store the binary data though, which is what I think you are seeing in cover column. If you want to send that data as a file back to the user check out rails' send_file.

Comment: @JoshLewis right now i'm saving the files in the root of the app, but the file names have characters before the .jpg, like "LTV_22.jpg?itok=Ec2cLySx". How i can remove this before characters and send this files to a specific folder?